# Unable to fetch Data using Data Source in YUI 2.X

Tags: javascript, yui

I have wriiten  a very small snippet using DataSource Utility  to fetch data from URL .  The problem is everytime i try executing the script , i get failure alerts.  On debugging thru chrome console , i see the data source request is not even made to the url .

The following is the code

```
    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("http://hostname.com:8590/status?");
myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_TEXT;

    var mySuccessHandler = function() {
            alert(myDataSource);
    };

var myFailureHandler = function() {
                     alert("failure");
                    alert(myDataSource);
    };

var callbackObj = {
        success : mySuccessHandler,
        failure : myFailureHandler
};

    myDataSource.sendRequest("job=1f179700-770f-11e1-9d97-458a3dcf55be",  callbackObj);
```

If the repose type is json  and if i use type_text . Will the datasource throw an error ?
 Is there any other way to fetch text from a particular url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it  [YUI forum](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=9724) . Seems like cross browser request is not supported. So , basically i did a  XHR request and handled the content instead of using Data Source.